# Migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL : where are the limits?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration, arcgis

I've found similar posts on this forum, but migrate it to another one if needed.

We want to migrate *to* PostgreSQL *from* Oracle, but we have 6000 users simultaneously connected to a  4 To GIS database(divided in 1 To instances) and many other instances for WebServices.

Before looking at other problems, we heard that 500 max connected users is the max limit supported before performances decrease, decrease augmented when size of database become huge.

Have you got any (or do you know links to) successful experience on such a migration?
Do we have to wait for PostgreSQL better performances to migrate?

---

*EDIT*

Found *[another example](http://www.zdnet.com/oracle-database-costs-are-driving-firms-to-postgres-says-enterprisedb-7000023384/)*.

Comment: Webservices (and most other clients) could probably benefit from connection pooling, eg http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer

Comment: @wildplasser exactly!!! Any system of this size where Users connect directly to the DB is most likely a bad architecture. The database shouldn't have to handle thousands of connections, which come and go. This should be done by the middle tier! - not just for the absolute limit, but also for mainainability, debugging, performance and safety

Answer (score 4):

Please, read [this article](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) on the subject by Kevin Grittner, it will explain a lot on why many connections are problematic and what were the decisions by the PostgreSQL Core Team to approach this issue.

For the list of success stories, refer to [the EnterpriseDB site](http://www.enterprisedb.com/success-stories), this is a company offering support for the standard PostgreSQL distribution as well as support and licensing for the advanced products built on top of standard distribution. For the enterprise database usage [Postgres Plus Advanced Server](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-advanced-server) might be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks, they are exactly links I'm searching.